# How to add lombok logging to gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, logging, lombok

I have a simple project on java with gradle.

Add lombok (as plugin), and try to use @Slf4j for logging

but there is no my printed messages on console, when i run application

Trying to add log4j.properties to project's resources, different dependencies but still not have log.

As workaround added

```
implementation 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
implementation 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
```

for using

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
```

and it's works with log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

How make work @Slf4j?

Comment: which implementation of Slf4j are you trying to use?
logback or log4j ?  slf4j is just a API requires implementation in the class path

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737204/how-slf4j-works-no-log-getting-created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sham says, resolution were in [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737204/how-slf4j-works-no-log-getting-created)

we must include this dependencies:

```
// logging
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:2.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:2.14.1'
```